# In Wired Connection settings save option is getting grayed out

Tags: networking, indicator, network-manager, connection, wired

Each time I switch to manual configuration, of wired connection in Ubuntu 12.10, the save button gets grayed out. As soon as I start setting it in Manually, it gets grayed out.Please help !

One more thing, system continuously  displays a message at the top-right corner of the screen, saying:

> Wired Network- Not connected

Comment: I've had the apply button not un-grey when the netmask put the gateway on a different subnet to the chosen IP. Really frustrating that there's zero error reporting for this.

Comment: I needed to check the "No CA certificate is required" on the security tab.

Comment: This seems to be a bug. I set up a (working) wifi connection. Everything was normal, but after a system reboot, I'm no longer able to edit this connection. So, (provably so), all information is correct. Yet, I can't save after making any (even minor) changes, e.g. checking or unchecking "all users may connect to this network". None of the solutions I'm finding provide a clear, general-case workaround yet.

Answer (score 6):

Found the solution: It's a GUI problem: When adding static IP you may end up with an 'invisible' blank line in the list of IP addresses which prevents saving settings - just click below your IP address and delete the blank entry.

Comment: this works, but for some weird reason even after saving and exiting out of the configuration I had to reboot for the changes to take effect

Comment: Doesn't work for me. No blank entry.

Comment: This worked for me with one small caveat. I had to add a blank line and then delete the blank line I just added. In my case, I didn't have a blank line just as Calmarius stated.

Answer (score 3):

The button is greyed-out if there a missing or wrong information filled in the fields. Make sure you put it in like this:

- IP Address: `192.168.1.20`
- Netmask: `24`
- Gateway: `192.168.1.1`
- DNS: `192.168.1.1` (not required for having a save-button)

Otherwhise please give us a Screenshot.

Comment: I put the same info and still the button is greyed out. Ubuntu network GUI is broken.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, the way around is to do it from command line.
Go to the file `/etc/network/interfaces` and change it to

```
auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
    address xx.xx.xx.xx
    netmask xx.xx.xx.xx
    gateway xx.xx.xx.xx
    dns-nameservers xx.xx.xx.xx
    dns-search xx
```

where you have to fill the `xx` given by your ISP.

Then from commandline do

```
sudo ifup eth0
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience this happens when information is missing. The so far mentioned answers are correct. I would also like to add additional scenario - wireless. In my case I had a **802.1x**. I couldn't save the password I have entered in my setting post-creation of the profile itself. I forgot to add the certificate. After I did that it all worked fine and the Save button was enabled again. In this case I could have also chosen the option not to require a certificate but either way one of both had to be entered as information.

In short - always check if you have entered all the information that is required from you for the network profile you are creating.