# Can't save network connections after editing (DNSCrypt)

Tags: networking, network-manager, system-settings, dnscrypt-proxy

I'm trying to setup DNSCrypt on Xubuntu 20.04.4. I've actually had it done once, just a few minutes ago, but I removed it when I was double checking it was functioning correctly.

Now as I try to restore the settings, I'm unable to save them:

[image]

I remember I had some problems saving the settings when I first tried it, but after clicking around it became available. I can't remember exactly what I did though and I can't repeat it.

Whenever I change IPv4 to 'manual' the save button greys out. I see this has been a bug since [2011](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/737615)

I had the settings exactly as shown in the screenshot before and I was able to save it, somehow.

I've tried the [invisible entries fix](https://askubuntu.com/a/435963/1073933) to no avail, and also hitting 'Enter' or 'Tab' but none of this works.

I was doing something with editing and deleting the 'Addresses' section previously, when I noticed 'save' became available. I've tried to repeat it, but I'm unable.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Yes, you're right, my bad it's 20.0.4

Comment: I don't know if you have fixed this, but normally I add an address (Add-button) and all is good. To me that's required as otherwise the interface wouldn't have an IP-address. I mean it wouldn't get it via DHCP.

Comment: @sjngm I did fix it, but the only way to do it is to set method to "automatic (DHCP) addresses only". Most (all) online guides say to set it to '"manual", but it's not possible to do that, it won't allow settings to be saved.